# ORA-31655 when using VERSION=10.2 with expdp

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, datapump

i'm trying to export a table with Oracle Datapump, running on a Oracle 12C Instance. The schema has a table called KAT.

When i do the export with:

```
expdp USER/PASS directory=exp dumpfile=dump.dmp logfile=kat.log TABLES=KAT
```

everything works as expected.

When i try to do the following (to be able to import the data in a Oracle 10g database), i get the following error:

```
expdp USER/PASS directory=exp dumpfile=dump.dmp logfile=kat.log TABLES=KAT VERSION=10.2

ORA-39166: Object USER.KAT was not found.
ORA-31655: no data or metadata objects selected for job
```

Why? Any ideas?

Comment: Does your KAT table have any foreign keys?

Comment: Yes, it does. Why would that be important? It only fails when i add the VERSION parameter.

Comment: Hope answer in this will solve yours https://community.oracle.com/thread/2258458?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely issue is that your table is using features that exist in 12c but not in 10.2. I'm getting the exact same error message trying to export a table with a virtual column (which were introduced in 11.1) from a 12c database:

- No `VERSION` (i.e. `COMPATIBLE`): works
- `VERSION=11.2` or `11.1`: works
- `VERSION=10.2`: `ORA-39166` error.

Could be a feature on the table itself, or one of its indexes (or constraints). Check the table's DDL.

Comment: Seems to be something like that. I've exported the table using VERSION=11.2 to an 11.2 Database, and then exported the table from there, using VERSION=10.2, seems to work.

Comment: That's very odd, the 11 -> 10 export shouldn't have worked either in the case I describe AFAIK, or there's some sort of conversion that took place. I'd recommend you compare the DDL between 12c and 10.2 closely, there might be a surprise.